# How to prevent entity framework code first from creating an index on a foreign key column

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

```
        mb.Entity<VintageDate>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Series)
            .WithMany(x => x.VintageDates)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.SeriesID);  // I am creating a composite index elsewhere, dont need this one.
```

How do I prevent EF from creating an index on SeriesID?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you probably have to explicitly drop the index in a subsequent migration.